# Spawning Tamed Ocelots

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is it possible to spawn already tamed ocelots a.k.a cats/kittens? Or spawn ocelots that are already in 'begging mode'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 3 types of tamed ocelots that can be summoned.

```
/summon Ozelot ~ ~ ~ {Owner:PlayerName,CatType:1}

/summon Ozelot ~ ~ ~ {Owner:PlayerName,CatType:2}

/summon Ozelot ~ ~ ~ {Owner:PlayerName,CatType:3}
```

(Type 1 is Tuxedo, Type 2 is tabby and type 3 is siamese)

Each of these can be summoned with cheats enabled or in creative mode.

More information on this topic can be found here:  https://www.digminecraft.com/game_commands/summon_tame_ocelot.php